# Is there a way to use like operator with an array in HiveQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql, sql-like

I am looking for a way to query a collect_set/list column with multiple values using `like` operator.
In the below example I am looking to get the rows that have one of the `values like '121%'`

```
id values
1 ["8001","12100"]
2 ["12134","9999","2222"]
3 NULL
4 ["5671","9765]
```

Result:

```
id values
1 ["8001","12100"] -- because of 121 in 2nd value of the collect_set
2 ["12134","9999","2222"] -- because of 121 in first value of the collect_set
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatenate array using some delimiter, for example `|` and use concatenated string in RLIKE operator.

Demo:

```
with mytable as (
select 1 id, array('8001','12100') as `values`
union all
select 2, array('12134','9999','2222')
union all
select 3, array() 
union all
select 4, array('5671','9765') 
)
select * from mytable
where concat('|',concat_ws('|',`values`),'|') rlike '\\|121'
```

Result:

```
id  values
1   ["8001","12100"]
2   ["12134","9999","2222"]
```

Note: Pipe `|` in regex needs to be escaped with double backslash.